# Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using Fragments for the first time and I'm trying to navigate from Activity to Fragment. The navigation is supposed to be handled by an OnClickListener (ImageView) that takes me to the said fragment. However, my fragment is not taking up the entire screen. I've set match-parent on the incoming view as well as the frame that's supposed to hold the Fragment. So overall, I'm  not sure if I'm having an XML misunderstanding or Java. I'll provide as much as I can below;

```
public class recipe_detail extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView mIngredientsTV;
    RecyclerView ingredientsRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView stepsRecyclerView;
    ImageView mBakingGif;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_detail);


        mBakingGif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.frag_container, new VideoFragment());
                ft.commit();
            }
        });


}



public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView mThumbnailImage;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_fragment, container, true);

    }


    // This event is triggered soon after onCreateView().
    // Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        mThumbnailImage = view.findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);


        Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        mThumbnailImage.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);


    }

}
```

---

```
<!--Activity to be Replaced-->

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ingredients_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Ingredients_header"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="INGREDIENTS" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#E0F2F1"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/ingredients_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/steps_label"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        </LinearLayout>


     <!-- Frame to hold fragment-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frag_container"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

```
<!--Fragment to be infalted-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/exo_content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/exo_player_view" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/short_description_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_tv" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Prev" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment that you are inflating will always take as much space as the container that is holding it. In your case, the container (FrameLayout) has its height as WRAP_CONTENT. Therefore, the fragment will take only the amount of space it needs to show its contents. What you can do is to set the height of the FrameLayout as MATCH_PARENT. This way the fragment will take up the entire screen space.

Just a note, when adding fragments on top of another view always remember to give your fragment layout some background color (by default its transparent). Otherwise your previous view will also remain visible through the fragment.

**EDIT (Explaining comment)**

You need to move the FrameLayout out of the ScrollView like such

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ingredients_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ingredients_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Ingredients_header"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="INGREDIENTS" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#E0F2F1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/ingredients_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/steps_label"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Frame to hold fragment-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

What I've done is move the fragment container out of the ScrollView. However, since an activity/fragment can have only 1 root element, I added a FrameLayout as a parent for both the ScrollView and the FrameLayout.

Comment: "Just a note, when adding fragments on top of another view always remember to give your fragment layout some background color (by default its transparent). Otherwise your previous view will also remain visible through the fragment.'' Noted..... However, I have changed the WRAP_CONTENT to MATCH_PARENT and now I have an IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Comment: I have fixed the IllegalStateException now and changed the WRAP_CONTENT to MATCH_PARENT but the Fragment is still coming halfway down the entire screen.

Comment: @pureskill75 give the following property to your FrameLayout. **android:layout_alignParentTop="true"**

Comment: Wont barge. However, if i change dimension of views in the incoming layout, there's movement, but I don't know if that's a good way of handling UI?

Comment: I think the problem is due to your fragment container being inside a scroll view. Just as a little test, move your fragment container outside the scroll view and set its width and height to MATCH_PARENT.

Comment: Tried that and it crushes and here is the error : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: @pureskill75 I meant move the FrameLayout to the same level as the ScrollView (not as its child)

Comment: Please say that again with different words, I didn't quite catch it

Comment: You killed it! It worked straight away,  I would never had thought of that. You saved me. Much appreciated!

Comment: @pureskill75 happy to help